# Polling Service in ASP.NET Webservice with Backgroundworker is not continueing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpapplication

I need to run a polling service in a ASP.NET-WebService. Now, I have implemented it with a `BackgroundWorker` which I am starting in `Application_Start` of the `HttpApplication`. This is working. But suddenly, it will not continue working anymore.

Now, I have the fallowing Question: 
What is the Lifetime for a `HttpApplication`, after it has started and executed `Application_Start`?
Have I to implement and run my `BackgroundWorker` at another place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is not designed for your use case. As quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread.

Normally asp.net app pool is configured (default IIS setting) to shut down after 20 minutes of idle time. Which is what I think is happening in your case.

You should develop a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx). Following is brief about the same:

> Windows services enable you to create long-running executable
>   applications that run in their own Windows sessions. These services
>   can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be paused
>   and restarted, and do not show any user interface. These features make
>   services ideal for use on a server or whenever you need long-running
>   functionality that does not interfere with other users who are working
>   on the same computer.

You can reuse all of your existing code. Just call you web service periodically from this windows service as per your requirement. That's it.